# Exception Exception is not compatible with throws clause in SpringAMQPMessageSource.onMessage(Message, Channel) Axon

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

I am working on Spring Boot + Axon Framework developing demo explain here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jp-rW-XOYzA&list=PLgGXSWYM2FpOa_FTla-x5Wd10dpmgrRC4&index=54. In this example I am only using latest dependencies, other stuff I keep the as is.

When I simply run the code I get the below error and already something wrong here at line.  Please guide me.

Error:-

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Exception Exception is not compatible with throws clause in SpringAMQPMessageSource.onMessage(Message, Channel)

    at com.example.DemoComplaintsStatsApplication$1.onMessage(DemoComplaintsStatsApplication.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:188) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:126) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1414) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1337) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:817) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:801) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1042) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

**DemoComplaintsStatsApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoComplaintsStatsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoComplaintsStatsApplication.class, args);
    }


    @ProcessingGroup("amqpEvents")
    @RestController
    public static class ComplaintStatisticsAPI {

        private ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> staticstics = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        @EventHandler
        public void on(ComplaintFileEvent event) {
            staticstics.computeIfAbsent(event.getCompany(), k -> new AtomicLong()).incrementAndGet();
        }

        @GetMapping
        public Map<String, AtomicLong> getStatistics(){
            return staticstics;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringAMQPMessageSource complaintEvents(Serializer serializer) {
        return new SpringAMQPMessageSource(new DefaultAMQPMessageConverter(serializer)) {

            @RabbitListener(queues = "ComplaintEvents")
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {
                super.onMessage(message, channel);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SpringAMQPMessageSource#onMessage(Message, Channel)` function used to be `SpringAMQPMessageSource#onMessage(Message, Channel) throws Exception`. That's however no longer the case as of 3.4.

I saw you've posted another StackOverflow on Axon Framework too, were you upgraded to version 3.4, correct?
I'd like to note 3.4 *is not* the latest release of the framework, as that's 4.0.
what 4.0 also includes is a very easy introduction into [Axon Server](https://axoniq.io/product-overview/axon-server), a free to use replacement for storing events and publishing messages (so commands, events and queries) between application. Shortly, it omits the need of the 'Spring AMQP' package entirely and should greatly simplify your code.

Nonetheless, to solve your issue, remove the `throws Exception` on your overridden `onMessage(Message, Channel)` function should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I will update my POC to use 4.0. Very great help. You can also use this POC to upgrade.